# Controlling access to AWS IoT policy actions for Cognito identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

[Documentation for IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-controlling-access-to.html#policies-specifying-policy-arn]) state that the `Resource`-property for `AttachUserPolicy` and `DetacherUserPolicy` should be set to the user principal the managed policy will be attached to. While the documentation for `iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy` and `iot:DetachPrincipalPolicy` are not as detailed, the error message

> AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/ROLE/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy on resource: COGNITO_ID

leads me to believe it expects an ARN for Cognito identity or identity pool. However, specifying ARNs shown in [Cognito documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/resource-permissions.html) result in the same error. Cognito identity ARNs also fail validation in the policy generator.

What resource should I specify so that `iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy` and `iot:DetachPrincipalPolicy` are permitted to attach/detach IoT policies on a Cognito identity?

Answer (score 15):

Using Cognito identities with AWS IoT has two slightly different paths. Cognito identity pools support identities which are either unauthenticated (any agent can get credentials) or authenticated (users tied to a provider like Cognito User Pools, Facebook, OpenID, etc). AWS IoT supports both cases when using Cognito to get credentials.

When using the unauthenticated case, you must attach a policy to the cognito_unauth_role that gets created with your Cognito identity pool. The Identity Access & Management (IAM) console is where you attach a policy to this role. To get started, try attaching the managed policy "AWSIoTDataAccess". Then, your unauthenticated Cognito IDs can get credentials (access key, secret key, session token) which are passed to AWS IoT to establish a connection.

When using the authenticated case, you must attach a policy to the cognito_auth_role that gets created with your Cognito identity pool *AND* the Cognito ID which is created for each authenticated entity. The AWS IoT API AttachPrincipalPolicy is what you use to attach an AWS IoT policy to the Cognito ID. The format of that API call in the CLI would be like: `aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name myPolicy --principal us-east-1:abcd1234-5678-1234-abcd1234efgh`. The principal in this case is the Cognito ID of the authenticated entity. Only with both policies in place will the credentials returned by Cognito work to make connections to AWS IoT.

Comment: Suppose a user just signed up, how do I attach a policy to the Cognito ID which is created for the authenticated entity? Is there a trigger I can use?

Comment: @webjay, Wow I came here with the same question? Do you have any solution to that?

Comment: @Roskoto we have the client attach a Policy made in IoT to the new user. Kinda weird, but it works.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to fit `AttachPolicy` instead of `AttachPrincipalPolicy`? because it is marked as deprecated now. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachPrincipalPolicy.html

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin, you cannot use `attachPolicy` API with Cognito Identity as this API only accepts  IOT certificate as a target. `attachPrincipalPolicy` API is what you need here; pass in the authenticated user/ entity's Cognito Identity ID returned in authentication process

Comment: @Waleed93 that cannot be true, `attachPrincipalPolicy` is marked as deprecated, i.e. there must be an alternative.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I second that. They direct to use `attachPolicy` as an alternative. I said while referring to AWS SDK API reference docs. But I checked a similar issue raised on github (see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3593). Hmm... really confusing as one was able to attach policy with Cognito Identity ID via CLI but not via SDK. I'd suggest to try using `attachPolicy`. If it doesn't work, then it's a bug. Better keep using `attachPrincipalPolicy` till bug is fixed in newer versions. It's deprecated meaning you can still use it but it'd be removed in future releases.